# Stuck on getting deps through a query

Tags: sql

I have a table, called refs, which has columns such as:

depname, refname, reftype.

Where, refname is the name of the table dependent on a view.

For this use case, I want to get all the views directly or indirectly dependent on  table(s) containing 'sapphire' in their name.

I'm not sure how to move ahead, and link the indirectly dependencies to views that indirectly depend on it. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: It's always welcomed sample data and expected output

Comment: My bad! Adding :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a few words, and using sql server (you didn't tag your rdbms), you can do it like this:

```
declare @objName varchar(100) = 'Saphire'

;with sample as (
  select 'V1' as vw, 'Saphire' as obj, 'Table' as objt union all
  select 'V2' as vw, 'V1' as obj, 'View' as objt union all
  select 'V3' as vw, 'V2' as obj, 'View' as objt
),
cte as (
  select vw, obj, objt from sample where obj = @objName -- anchor member
  union all
  -- recursive member
  select s.vw, s.obj, s.objt
  from sample s
    join cte c
      on c.vw = s.obj
)
select * from cte
```

You can test on [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=201a30d415335da9df236e7e7b0437e9) db<>fiddle

CTE behaves in a very particular way, compared with the behaviour of usual sql queries. CTE uses an anchor member and a recursive member within the CTE definition. It helps get hierarchies within a table.

Comment: @zlata_x, I don't understand well what you want. That's why I recommended you to add your expected output. As you can see in he answer, I have had to invent your data just to show you the behaviour of recursive CTE

Comment: @zlata_x its just a matter of alias on the output, you can check it on this fiddle => https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d994cc31f76593ffb7f513c6d0afec09

Comment: My answer returns exactly your expected output. I highly recommend you to stop and think about what you are asking and reformule your question, adding your rdbms tag, sample data and expected output. Please, help us to help.